# $\sum E_{x} |V_k - V_{k-1}|I\{\tau_C \ge k\} = \sum E_x[|E[(V_k - V_{k-1})|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]I\{\tau_C \ge k\}|]$ for a submartingale Markov chain.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $V$ be a non-negative function that satisfies 
$$E_x V(y) - V(x) \ge 0, \; x\in C^c.$$
Let $\tau_C := \min\{n\ge 1: \Phi_n \in C\}$, where $\Phi_n$ is a Markov chain. Let $V_k = V(\Phi_k)$. In this case, how do we get the following equality? 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{x} |V_k - V_{k-1}|\mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty E_x[|E[(V_k - V_{k-1})|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]\mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\}|].$$

I can see that on $\{\tau_C \ge k\}$, $E[V_k - V_{k-1}|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}] \ge 0$ and  $\{\tau_C \ge k\}$ is $\mathscr{F}_{k-1}$- measurable, so we can take it out, but then the RHS is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_x[E[(V_k - V_{k-1})|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]\mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\}]$. I can't see how this is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{x} |V_k - V_{k-1}|\mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\}$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: This is simply using $$|E(XY\mid \mathscr G)|=|E(X\mid  \mathscr G)Y|$$ under integrability conditions, as soon as $Y$ is $ \mathscr G$-measurable, for $$X=V_k-V_{k-1}\qquad  \mathscr G=\mathscr F_{k-1}\qquad Y=\mathbf 1\{\tau_C\geqslant k\}$$

Comment: @Did But here we on the LHS we have $E|X|Y = E[E[|X|Y | \mathscr{G}]]$ and the RHS is $E[|E(X | \mathscr{G})Y|]$. So the LHS has the absolute value inside the iterated expectations whereas the RHS has it outside the conditional expectation.

Comment: True remark. Since, with the notations in my first comment, $$E[|X|\cdot Y] = E[E[|X|\mid\mathscr G]\cdot Y]$$ one would expect $$E_x[E[|V_k - V_{k-1}|\mid\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]\mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\}]$$ on the RHS, instead of $$E_x[|E[V_k - V_{k-1}\mid\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]\mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\}|]$$ Has this any consequence later on?

Comment: @Did Yes this is used for showing that $\sum_{k \ge 1} E_x[|V_k-V_{k-1} \mathbb{I}\{\tau_C \ge k\}|] < \infty$. But I guess this is a mistake from the author as what you have is enough for showing this.